# xcode start simulation in specific line, view, or point

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

It's not a question about code, it's possible? because i have a project with many view and testing is not to fast.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a different view in your root controller at
`-applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions:`

Comment: But is the better way? It's strange there is not a clean method.

Answer (score 0):

its possible but in some view you will get problem because your some view based on those view which are't loading.

by the way here is code

```
         - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
             {
            self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

            self.YourviewController = [[[self.YourviewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"self.YourviewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

            self.window.rootViewController = self.YourviewController;

            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

            return YES;
```

}